# rails -s won't start up anymore on Rails 5.2.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I don't know where to start in tracking what went wrong here. A day ago all was well, now the server won't start. Any ideas what is wrong here? using Rails 5.2.4.1.

```
admins-Mac-mini-2:newapp admin$ rails -s
2020-01-20 11:59:42 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
Run options: --seed 22131

# Running:

E

Error:
RulesControllerTest#test_should_get_task:
ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
    (sass):7284
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___839783142231464888_70314399652940'
    test/controllers/rules_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:RulesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/rules_controller_test.rb:4



Finished in 2.060711s, 0.4853 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
admins-Mac-mini-2:caselaw admin$
```

Answer (score 0):

With `rails -s` you are starting your test suite.

If you want to start your server you should do : `rails s` or `rails server`